# Unable to redirect if href is changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html looks like this :-

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="shopall-anchor"><div class="" id="shopall-btn"></div></a>
```

If i click on the button, it redirects to www.google.com ( as it should ).
I am trying to change the href dynamically through jQuery like this :-

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function() {
    $('#shopall-anchor').attr("href","www.microsoft.com");
    return false;
});
```

After debugging i found out that the href is changed to microsoft.com after the click event, but i am unable to redirect the user to www.microsoft.com

Is there anything which i am missing ?

**Edit 1:-**

I tried doing the following things, but unable to find a solution:-
1) The page is redirected to "www.google.com" as mentioned initially in the anchor tag for the below solution.

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function() {
    location.href = "www.microsoft.com";   
});
```

2) "www.microsoft.com" is appended in my current link if i do something like this :-

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();       // prevents default behaviour
    $('#shopall-anchor').attr("href","www.microsoft.com");
   return true;  // activate click
});
```

**Edit 2 :-**

Check my answer if you have the same issue and the href link is appending to the current url.

Comment: What are you actually using this for? Changing a link when a user clicks it seems like something that could be very easily exploited for nefarious purposes.

Comment: @RobinNeal but the thing is, i am getting the link from backend and i need to change the current link accordingly. As in the database, it is updated every 10-15 days.

Comment: If you're getting it from the backend, surely you could just change it serverside? or simply do something like
`$('a').attr('href', newlink);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following code.

```
<!-- <a id="shopall-anchor"> -->
<div class="" id="shopall-btn"></div>
<!-- </a> -->
```

i.e. removed the anchor tag completely.

and binded click event on the button like this :-

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function(e) {
    document.location.href='http://www.pipabella.com';
});
```

Hope it helps someone.

**Edit 1:-**

Alternatively, this can also be done if you want to use anchor tag:-

```
$('#shopall-anchor').attr("href", "http://www.microsoft.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it is appending to the current URL is because you are using the relative URL since you have not used the `http://` in the link.

```
$('#shopall-anchor').attr("href", "http://www.microsoft.com");
```

This is the main reason of the invalid redirect and for rest issues, you already have the answers:

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function() {
    var newURL = "http://www.microsoft.com";
    // This will just change the href (technically of no use)
    $("#shopall-anchor").attr("href", newURL);

    // Actually redirect to the different page
    document.location.href = newURL;

    // Prevent all other navigation
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Working super fine !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.href`. In jQuery

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function() {
    location.href = "www.microsoft.com";   
  });
```

in Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("shopall-btn").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "www.microsoft.com"; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#shopall-btn').click(function() {
    $('#shopall-anchor').attr("href","www.microsoft.com");
    //return false;//remove it,it stops the event propagation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

jQuery Library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then html code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> <div class="" id="shopall-btn"></div></a>
```

then this is jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#shopall-btn').click(function(e) {
    window.location.href='http://www.microsoft.com';
   });
</script>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: how is it different from my solution ? i removed the anchor tag because it seemed unnecessary.

Comment: if someone want to show anchor tag or sometime jQuery onlick function use then need to use anchor tag that why anchor tag use but if no need then also remove it

Comment: i still didnt get your purpose. For onclick we have already binded the event jusing jQuery .click() function.

Comment: if question provider want to use anchor tag must for other purpose like use css or anchor  tag generate dynamic so question provider use this tag for this purpose